# PeriodAxis incorrect TimeZone

Tags: java, timezone, jfreechart

Using the **DateAxis** it works fine:

```
// From: 2/5/13 02:00:00 PM (+1), To: 2/5/13 03:00:00 PM (+1)
// Configuring dataset
Timezone tz = new SimpleTimeZone(1, "Test");
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(tz);
TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries("Series1");
...
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timestamp1), tz, locale), value1);
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timestamp2), tz, locale), value2);
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timestamp3), tz, locale), value3);
...
// Setting axis timezone
((DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis()).setTimeZone(tz);
((DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis()).setRange(new DateRange(
           from, to), true, true);
```

[image: DateAxis Chart]

But when I try to do the same with the **PeriodAxis** it displays a incorrect time zone. Looks like it is getting the timezone from my computer (-3).

```
// From: 2/5/13 02:00:00 PM (+1), To: 2/5/13 03:00:00 PM (+1)
// Configuring dataset
Timezone tz = new SimpleTimeZone(1, "Test");
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(tz);
TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries("Series1");
...
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timestamp1), tz, locale), value1);
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timestamp2), tz, locale), value2);
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timestamp3), tz, locale), value3);
...
// Setting periodAxis
PeriodAxis periodaxis = new PeriodAxis("");

periodaxis.setFirst(new Millisecond(new Date(from), tz));
periodaxis.setLast(new Millisecond(new Date(to), tz));

periodaxis.setTimeZone(tz);

periodaxis.setRange(new DateRange(from, to), true, true);
periodaxis.setAutoRangeTimePeriodClass(Second.class);
PeriodAxisLabelInfo aperiodaxislabelinfo[] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo[2];
aperiodaxislabelinfo[0] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo(
        org.jfree.data.time.Minute.class, new SimpleDateFormat("mm"));
aperiodaxislabelinfo[1] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo(
        org.jfree.data.time.Hour.class, new SimpleDateFormat("HH"));
periodaxis.setLabelInfo(aperiodaxislabelinfo);

chart.getXYPlot().setDomainAxis(periodaxis);
```

[image: Period Axis Chart]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found two ways to solve this problem:

### Frist

Setting the timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
...
SimpleDateFormat dfMin = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
dfMin.setTimeZone(tz); // Setting timezone
PeriodAxisLabelInfo aperiodaxislabelinfo[] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo[2];
aperiodaxislabelinfo[0] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo(
        org.jfree.data.time.Minute.class, dfMin);
SimpleDateFormat dfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
dfHour.setTimeZone(tz); // Setting timezone
aperiodaxislabelinfo[1] = new PeriodAxisLabelInfo(
        org.jfree.data.time.Hour.class, dfHour);
periodaxis.setLabelInfo(aperiodaxislabelinfo);
...
```

---

### Second

Also reported this as a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/bugs/1107/), IMO the axis must respect the `periodaxis.setTimeZone(tz);` instruction. This line should be added to [PeriodAxis.java](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/PeriodAxis.html#line.888):

```
885        while (p.getFirstMillisecond() <= axisMax) {
886            float x = (float) valueToJava2D(p.getMiddleMillisecond(), dataArea,
887                    edge);
888            DateFormat df = this.labelInfo[band].getDateFormat();

               df.setTimeZone(timeZone); // Missing timezone setting

889            String label = df.format(new Date(p.getMiddleMillisecond()));
890            long first = p.getFirstMillisecond();
891            long last = p.getLastMillisecond();
892            if (last > axisMax) {
```